# Row with columns equal height inside a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with making all columns the same height.

I know how to do it when I'm not using ng-repeat. I do it like this .

http://www.bootply.com/uj9u4mPIsS#

But when I want to do it in the same way with ng-repeat , it messes up everything. It works when my right div `col-md-9`  is not longer than my left div `col-md-3`, 
When my `col-md-9` is longer tho, it changes position and starts stacking the Db under `col-md-3` which I don't want.

And I don't want to solve it by doing a float right on my right div. I want to solve it in an ordinary way with bootstrap just like I did with the bootply above. Any suggestions what I did wrong? Sorry if I'm not clear.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div id="about" class="container-fluid" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">
  <form>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="model" value="Iphone">Option 1</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 2</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="" disabled>Option 3</label><br>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 " ng-repeat="x in products ">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">{{x.brand}</div>    
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12">}{{x.name}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12">{{x.color}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.row{
    overflow: hidden; 

}

.row [class*="col-"]{
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
```

my "db"

```
 var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.model = false;
      $scope.products = [
        {
        brand: 'Ferrari',
        name: 'Enzo',
        color: 'Black',
        },
      {
        brand: 'Ferrari',
        name: 'F80',
        color: 'Yellow',
      },
      {
        brand: 'Ferrari',
        name: 'F430',
        color: 'Red',
      },
          {
        brand: 'Ferrari',
        name: 'Enzo',
        color: 'Black',
        },
      {
        brand: 'Ferrari',
        name: 'F80',
        color: 'Yellow',
      },
      {
        brand: 'Ferrari',
        name: 'F430',
        color: 'Red',
      },
          {
        brand: 'Ferrari',
        name: 'Enzo',
        color: 'Black',
        },
      {
        brand: 'Ferrari',
        name: 'F80',
        color: 'Yellow',
      },
      {
        brand: 'Ferrari',
        name: 'F430',
        color: 'Red',
      },
      ]
    });
```

Comment: wrap inner divs of ng-repeat inside another parent div with class=row

Comment: is it not what i did with with ng-repeat? Or can you do a bootply please

Comment: i have two col-3, i want the upper one , the first col-3 to be as high as the right col-9

Comment: Think u mixed it up with the col-3 inside of the col-9

Comment: @ZimSystem  Did u understand what i ment? I want the left div to be same height as the right div, i dotn want the right div to go under the left when the left div ends.

Comment: this is the one you made. codeply.com/go/z97dnsvybB  . and this is how i want it to look. http://www.codeply.com/go/fVeBHDdVZZ but i dont wanna solve it with float:right; i wanna do it ordenary way with collums and row without float etc.

Comment: You can use nesting: http://www.codeply.com/go/E90H9oP5nG